# Resizing images in contentEditable-div stopped working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable, content-editor

Unfortunately resizing and selecting images in a div with contenteditable attribute stopped working after a firefox update (64.0). Is there anything I need to change / add a flag or something to keep it working?

Example code: https://codepen.io/danielpixelz/pen/PXGeaN

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="i-want-to-be-editable">
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved. It's disabled by default now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1449564

needed to activate it manually by using

```
document.execCommand(enableObjectResizing, false, "true")
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand